# Way for Delete the table data with the ng-click directive and change the IsDelete flag to true in the database while keeping the data in the database

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

If anyone can give me some tips on how to make my button delete a record via the ng-click deleteRegister directive.

My idea is to delete a row from the table in my Register.cshtml but on the server change the flag isDelete to true without deleting the database record, just keep the data, but with the IsDelete flag as true.

I'll leave the code snippet for better understanding.

Every help is welcome!
My view html is here:

```
<div class="row" style="">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none">Id</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>Ativo</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Remover</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="register in registers">
                    <td style="display:none">{{register.UserId}}</td>
                    <td>{{register.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{register.LastName}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="register.IsActive" disabled /></td>
                    <td>{{register.Email}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a ng-click="editRegister($event, register)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" ng-click="deleteRegister(register.UserId)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my controller.js

```
$scope.deleteRegister = function (userId) {
    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:51734/api/UserAPI",
        data: userId
    });
    post.success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.registers = $scope.registers.filter(function (register) {
            return register.UserId !== userId;
        })
    })
```

And my server,in the backend:

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("api/UserAPI/Delete")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var register = ctx.User.Find(id);
            if (register != null)
            {
                register.IsDelete = true;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Usuário não encontrado");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: .. so what, exactly, is the problem? The code looks like it will work.

Comment: You have 3 errors.
1- TypeError: post.success is not a function
    at ChildScope. $ scope.deleteRegister (registerController.js: 66)
2- DELETE http: // localhost: 51734 / api / UserAPI1008 404 (Not Found)

3- Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data": {"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the URI request 'http: // localhost: 51734 / api / UserAPI1008'.", "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'UserAPI1008'. "}," status ": 404," config ": {" method ":" DELETE "

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can already remove a line in my view.cshtml, now I'm just trying to keep the value that already exists in my database by changing only one property of that object, which is boolean isDelete to true.

So, my person object has an id, first name, last name, date of birth, and my IsDelete boolean variable, when I click the delete, it keeps the object on the server and changes the IsDelete property to true.

My controller.js:

```
$scope.deleteRegister = function (register) {
    var index = -1;
    var listOfRegister = eval($scope.registers);
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfRegister.length; i++) {
        if (listOfRegister[i].register === register) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index === -1) {
        alert("Something gone wrong");
    }
    $scope.registers.splice(index, 1);
    $http({
        method: 'Delete',
        url: 'http://localhost:51734/api/UserAPI/',

    }).then(function (res) {
        alert('Success Del');
        $scope.GetAllRegisters();
    })
};
```

My index.cshtl:

```
<td>
 <a href="" ng-click="deleteRegister(register)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
</td>
```

And my api controller:

```
//DELETE: api/UserAPI/5
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/UserAPI")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(UserViewModel uservm)
    {
        try
        {
            User usr = new Models.User();

            var register = ctx.User.Where(x => x.UserId == uservm.UserId).SingleOrDefault();
            uservm.IsDelete = true;
            if (register != null)
            {
                register.IsDelete = uservm.IsDelete;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Record not found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }

    }
```

I believe that this is as clear as I can be, from the following goal I want to achieve.
Thanks.